# Hql In Clause on List

Tags: many-to-many, hql

i want to make a query like this

```
createQuery("FROM Grouping g WHERE :user IN g.groupMembers OR :userId=g.groupAdminId")
```

But hibernate translates it to

```
snuser2_.id and ('12' in (.) or '12'=grouping0_.groupAdminId)
```

g.groupMembers is a List (@ManyToMany), how can i use the IN operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Grouping g where :user member of g.groupMembers or g.groupAdminId = :userId
```